# Reading tag from HTML file in c++

Tags: c++

I got these questions that I stuck for the past week, "tag always starts with '<' and ends with '>'link always starts with "<a" or "<A" and ends with '>'comment always starts with "<!--" and ends with "- ->",

How can I count these using only while loop or other loops? I'm in the intro programming class, anything beyond loop, if and switch statement is not allowed to use.

Here is the program I done so far and I can't count the the lines and links at the same time, but if I break them apart, I can get the result I want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream inFile;

char ch,
prevchar,
currchar;

int linenum = 0,
    tagnum = 0,
    commentnum = 0,
    linknum = 0,
    cfilenum = 0,
    ctagnum = 0;

double percent;

string line;

string filename;

cout << "========================================\n";
cout << "           HTML File Analyzer\n";
cout << "========================================\n\n";
cout << "Please enter the the file name(no blank): \n";
cin >> filename;
inFile.open(filename.c_str());
while (!inFile)
{
    cout << "Please re-enter the file name:\n";
    cin >> filename;
    inFile.open(filename.c_str());
}

cout << "========================================\n";
cout << "           Text of the file           \n";
cout << "========================================\n\n";
while (inFile)
{
    for (linenum = 0; getline(inFile, line); linenum++);

}

inFile.get(prevchar);
inFile.get(currchar);
while (inFile)
{
    if ((prevchar == '<') && (currchar == 'a'))
        linknum++;
    prevchar = currchar;
    inFile.get(currchar);
}

cout << "========================================\n";
cout << "           End of the text           \n";
cout << "========================================\n\n";
cout << "Analysis of file\n";
cout << "----------------\n\n";

cout << "Number of lines: " << linenum << endl;
cout << "Number of tags: " << tagnum << endl;
cout << "Number of comments: " << commentnum << endl;
cout << "Number of links: " << linknum << endl;
cout << "Number of chars in file: " << cfilenum << endl;
cout << "Number of chars in tags: " << ctagnum << endl;
cout << "Percentage of characters in tags: " << percent << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Has the instructor taught the class how to debug the source? Try running the code line by line and observe which could be wrong. From a quick look alot of requirements are not met. For example I don't see a code that counts the comments. The link tag as you said can be <a or <A, I only see an attempt for <a. They key is knowing the codes line by line

Comment: A colleague of yours has been asking questions about the same assignment on StackOverflow recently.

Comment: Just think about the two loops `while (inFile)`. If the first loop finished, can you expect the second loop run?

Answer (score -1):

After the first loop has finished, your `inFile` stream is pointing to the end of the file and its eof flag is set.

Issue these statements inbetween your loops to resp. clear the flag and go back to the start of the file:

```
inFile.clear();
inFile.seekg(0);
```

That the first statement is not necessary in C++11, but I don't know what environment you are using. Also note that you can do some of the counting operations together in a loop.